# How to access Attribute data from within a method

Tags: postsharp

I have a PostSharp class like this:

```
[Serializable] 
public sealed class TraceAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{ 
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) 
    { 
        public Dictionary<string, object> tt 
             = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        tt.Add("WebServiceName", args.Method.DeclaringType.Namespace); 

        for (int x = 0; x < args.Arguments.Count; x++) 
        { 
           // ignore ref parameters 
           if (!args.Method.GetParameters()[x].ParameterType.IsByRef) 
               tt.Add(args.Method.GetParameters()[x].Name, args.Arguments.GetArgument(x)); 
        }

        // call to my custom logging with parameter name and values in tt
        // …

        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;

        base.OnException(args); 
     } 
}
```

And this is used by my code in this way in a web service:

```
[WebMethod,Trace] 
public int TestFunction(string Param1, string Param2, string ref error) 
{ 
    try
    {
        bool test = true;
        if (test)
        {
             error =  "this is a test exction";

             throw new Exception (error);
        }

        return 1;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         error = ex.Message;

         throw ex;
     }

     return 2;
}
```

The problem I have is that my test method never returns 2. How can this be done?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the issue, you can visualize how the OnException aspect is weaved into your method's code. It basically wraps the whole method body into a try-catch block. So, the result looks similar to the following:

```
[WebMethod,Trace] 
public int TestFunction(string Param1, string Param2, string ref error) 
{ 
    try
    {
        try
        {
            bool test = true;
            if (test)
            {
                 error =  "this is a test exction";

                 throw new Exception (error);
            }

            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;

            throw ex;
        }

        return 2;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Call to TraceAspect.OnException
    }
    // The execution will continue here
}
```

As you can see, the exception is caught and re-thrown in the first `catch`. After that, it is caught again in the second `catch`. At this point the `return 2;` statement is already skipped.

You can set the new return value of the method in the aspect by setting `args.ReturnValue` whenever you set `args.FlowBehavior` to `Continue` or `Return` (these two values are equivalent in case of the exception flow behavior, see [FlowBehavior Enumeration](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_flowbehavior)).

For example:

```
[Serializable] 
public sealed class TraceAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{ 
    private object returnValue;

    public TraceAspect(object returnValue)
    {
        this.returnValue = returnValue;
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) 
    { 
        public Dictionary<string, object> tt 
             = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        tt.Add("WebServiceName", args.Method.DeclaringType.Namespace); 

        for (int x = 0; x < args.Arguments.Count; x++) 
        { 
           // ignore ref parameters 
           if (!args.Method.GetParameters()[x].ParameterType.IsByRef) 
               tt.Add(args.Method.GetParameters()[x].Name, args.Arguments.GetArgument(x)); 
        }

        // call to my custom logging with parameter name and values in tt
        // …

        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
        args.ReturnValue = this.returnValue;

        base.OnException(args); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is fine. But how can I get the exception type in OnException ? The value is always null ?